# SharePoint 2010 Public Content Deployment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, anonymous-access

I am trying to set up content deployment. Our situation will be that the authoring site will sit under https:// and deploy to a http:// publishing site. We want to keep the authoring site secure while making the http:// publishing site, public.

Do I enable anonymous access on the authoring site as it must mirror onto the publishing. Or Enable anonymous access on the publishing site?